# Where can I find Saikawa Sensei's shirts for sale?

Tags: merchandise, subete-ga-f-ni-naru

I'd like to find Saikawa's shirts without printing them myself.

[image: Picture of Saikawa's shirts]

Have these shirts been made available as licensed product?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find the パン shirt available on Crunchyroll's [store](http://www.crunchyroll.com/store/p/174253/Crunchyroll-Exclusive-The-Perfect-Insider-Pan-Medium) as a Crunchyroll exclusive product.

[image: Picture from Crunchyroll's store of the pan shirt]

They do not have the other shirts available on their store though.